# Extjs form not submitting its values

Tags: forms, extjs

I have this function that creates a form and the form not submitti its values, what is wrong?
It submits empty ajax, If I change the third line to `applyTo:document.body` it works fine.
(the `tab` variable is a tab panel that the form needs to be on it)

```
function myFunction(tab) {
    var frm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        applyTo: tab.id,
        height: 250,
        id: 'frm',
        name: 'frm',
        layout: 'form',
        width: 520,
        url: 'operation/DataManipulator/',
        method: "post",
        labelWidth: 200,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'users',
            id: "users",
            fieldLabel: 'How many users to create?'
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function (btn, evt) {
                frm.getForm().submit();
            }
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting "scope: this" after "text:'Submit'" or try inside your handler function:

```
function(btn, evt) {
    Ext.getCmp('frm').getForm().submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `method` config should be `method : 'POST'`. The `POST` is case sensitive.

Comment: thanks, but it did not help. but I discovered that if I do `applyTo:document.body` it submits the form. thanks